# What is type-ahead like in input field And how to shut it

Tags: html

I encounter this 
[choice that looks like type-ahead thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZQrC.png)

I know it from what I have type on the same element name before but how do I shut it? 
I have my ui-bootstrap to make more dynamic type-ahead but this is always get in the way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That looks like html5 autocomplete that you can turn off: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: thanks! 
and could you please tell me why I got -2 on my question?

Comment: The people that voted the question down will have to answer that.

Comment: I'm new here maybe i did something wrong or things they not usually do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually the autocomplete attribute. Set the it to off:

```
<input [...] autocomplete="off">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion